# TFS Build fails even though same build from command line works

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a TFS CI build that fails every time although if I go to the TFS console and copy the exact command that's being executed and copy/paste it to a CMD prompt on the same machine and run it it runs fine. How is that possible? I've run into situations where a different version of MSBuild was being called by TFS but the command specifies exactly where to find MSBuild so that can't be it. The first of many errors is: "*Shared\QCImage\GliffTool.cs(4,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PacsForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*" If I run this build within VS it works fine but the real kicker is that the **exact** command works when run directly. What the heck is going on?

This is TFS Version 15.117.26714.0 hosted locally. And no - upgrading is not an option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How is that possible?

The most likely reason is that you are using the Microsoft-hosted agent. So no matter which machine your TFS is running on, the pipeline is running on a cloud agent.

Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents) for more detailed information about self-hosted agent and Microsoft-hosted agent

If you don't mind using self-hosted agent to run the pipeline, you can set up it by the links below. In this way, your pipelines are equivalent to running locally and they won't be subject to Microsoft's pipeline billing restrictions.

- [Self-hosted Linux
  agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=tfs-2015)
- [Self-hosted macOS
  agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=tfs-2015)
- [Self-hosted Windows
  agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=tfs-2015)

**Please Notice the version selection above the left navigation bar.**

If you want to run your pipeline using Microsoft-hosted agent, the error you met is that your app cannot find `PacsForm`. It is not installed on the Microsoft-hosted agent.

If `PacsForm` is a NuGet package, you need to use the [NuGet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=tfs-2018) task to restore it.

If not, you need to include it in your repository and edit your reference in your application. Note that your app reference must not contain absolute paths.

Comment: Nope - using a local agent.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - it just started working. Yesterday it didn't - today it does(?). No explanation.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao - why would you delete my post where I said this exact thing yesterday?